# Google Script - Cannot get more than 100 elements into an Array

Tags: google-apps-script, httpresponse, zendesk, zendesk-api

I currently have an issue with Google Script. I try to make an HTTP GET request from our ticket system, which delivers all open tickets. 
This actually works without any problems, but the problem is, that I never get a response with more than 100 elements back (even if there are about 150 open tickets), so the array cannot contain more than 100 elements. Is there any reason for this?
Anyone knows a solution?

Code snippet:

```
  function setOpenTickets() {
  const subdomain = getSubdomain();
  const username = getUsername();
  const token = getToken();

  const searchUrlOpen = "https://" + subdomain + ".zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?" +
    "query=type:ticket status:open order_by:created sort:asc";

  const authToken = username + "/token:" + token;
  const encodedAuthToken = Utilities.base64Encode(authToken);
  const options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-type":"application/xml",
      "Authorization":  "Basic " + encodedAuthToken
    }
  };

  const jsonResponseOpen = fetchJson(searchUrlOpen, options);
  const openTickets = jsonResponseOpen.results.length;

  Logger.log("Open Tickets: " + openTickets);
  getConfigurationSheet().getRange("B16").setValue(openTickets);
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with relevant code snippet ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair Sorry, I added the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zendesk API documentation says : The Search API returns a limit of 2,000 pages with `100 results per page`

Please query through all the pages to get all the data.

Something like this: (please check response status and break loop if 422 or empty page is returned)

```
var page = 1;
response = fetchJson(searchUrlOpen+"&page="+page++, options);
while (response.status_code != 422) {
    processResponse(response);
    response = fetchJson(searchUrlOpen+"&page="+page++, options);
}
```

Reference : https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search#results-limit

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't even think about checking the documentation of the Zendesk API. Typical beginner fail.

Comment: Same pinch! (for beginner) :p

Comment: Rule #1 of software development - Always Reference Canonical Documentation.